# Capitalising the first letter of all cards in Anki?

Tags: regex, anki

I have a deck with about 5000 cards with 1 word in each card, and I want to capitalise the first letter in all those cards.

I tried doing it with regex find-and-replace, but all the variations I've tried don't work in Anki, for example:

Card: `hello`
Input: `(^[a-z])`
Replace: `\U1`

But that doesn't work. Even variations of that don't do anything.

How can I use regex to do this properly? If not regex, is there any other way to do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of the special syntax of [anki](/questions/tagged/anki), but in `sed`-syntax, without bash escapes, you can use

```
Input: (^[a-z])([a-z]*)
Replace: \U\1\E\2
```

- `\U` denotes an uppercase conversion
- `\1` is the first encapsulated string
- `\E` does end the `\U` uppercase sequence.
- `\2` is the rest of the string (the second encapsulated string)

Comment: Unfortunately this syntax does not work with Anki, it just replaces things with the literal string of the replace expression.

Answer (score 0):

A non-regex way would be to [export the data to .csv](https://superuser.com/a/1523864/944444), do the replacement using a spreadsheet program such as Excel, and then reimport the data to Anki. Your number of rows is way lower than Excel's maximum. To change lower case to upper case in Excel, use CHAR(CODE(A1)-32).