# How to print cards from an Anki deck, one card per line?

Tags: anki

For example, say I have a vocabulary deck with two fields, one for each word or phrase and one for its definition. How can I print out a simple list, for example in .csv format, with each line containing the content of a card's first field followed by the content of its second, for pasting into a text editor or word processor?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question didn't take long to find an answer to. There's [an add-on at AnkiWeb.net](https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1478130872) that enables exporting to .csv. Job done.